# The Lebesgue Measure of the Cantor Set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Why is it that m(C+C) = 2, where C is the Cantor set, but C is itself measure zero?  What is happening that makes this change occur?  Is it true generally that m(A+B) =/= m(A) + m(B)?  Are there cases in which this necessarily holds?  I should note that this is all within the usual topology on R.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding two sets $A$ and $B$ is in general much more than taking the union of a copy of $A$ and a copy of $B$.

Rather, $A+B$ can be seen as made up of many slices that look like $A$ (one for each $b\in B$), and the Cantor set has the same size as the reals, so here we have in fact as many slices as real numbers. Therein lies the problem: Even $m(A+\{1,2\})$ may be larger than $m(A)+m(\{1,2\})$, and it can be as large as $2m(A)$ (think, for example, of $A=[0,1]$). -- Of course, the slices do not need to be disjoint in general, but this is another issue.

Ittay's answer indicates that if $A,B$ are countable we have $m(A+B)=m(A)+m(B)$, more or less for trivial reasons. There does not seem to be a natural way of generalizing this to the uncountable, in part because Lebesgue measure can never be $\mathfrak c$-additive, meaning that even if we have that $A_r$ is a measurable set for each $r\in\mathbb R$, and it happens that $\sum_r m(A_r)$ converges, and it happens that the $A_r$ are pairwise disjoint, in general $m(\bigcup_r A_r)$ and $\sum_r m(A_r)$ are different. For example, consider $A_r=\{r\}$.

Comment: Good idea.  $[0,1]$ has measure $1$ and $\mathbb Z$ has measure zero, but what is the measure of their sum?

Comment: It would be infinity, correct?  Is this to say then that we need to be careful when stating that Lebesgue measure is translation invariant?

Comment: Lebesgue measure is translation invariant.  But that has nothing to do with sums of sets.

Comment: Right, sorry.  So it is infinity because the way we add elements of Z to [0,1] results in the whole real line if the two are added.  I was, mistakenly if I understand you correctly, generalizing from adding one element to every element of A to adding a set of elements to A.

Comment: Why only "$m(A+\{1,2\})$ [...] can be as large as $2m(A)$" rather than precisely twice the size unless overlapping?

Comment: @Freeze_S I think the overlapping case is more interesting, so I chose a phrasing that emphasizes it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in general $m(A+B) \ne m(A)+m(B)$.  Equality does hold when $m(A+B)=0$, but for trivial reasons.

Comment: Thank you!  One further question:

I noticed that inner measures are super-additive in all cases while  outer measures are sub-additive only in the case that the union of sets, say S,T, is disjoint.  Why do we not require that the union is disjoint in the case of inner measure?  That is, why does super-additivity hold regardless.

Comment: @Stop: You may add the disjointness requirement if you wish.  But non-disjoint superadditivity would easily follow from disjoint superadditivity, so why bother?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, it should be clear then that super additivity will not run into the same problems as subadditivity when it comes to disjointness and so no distinction will need to be made?  Is there an equivalent requirement that could be made that is in some way equivalent to the disjointness requirement for equality between sums and unions in the case of the Lebesgue outer measure?

Answer (score 3):

When $m(A)=m(B)=0$ and $A$ is countable then $m(A+B)=0$. This is so because $A+B=\bigcup _{a\in A}a+B$ is a countable union, and $m$ is translation invariant so $m(a+B)=m(B)=0$, so countable (sub)additivity gives that $m(A+B)=0$.

However, when both $A$ and $B$ are uncountable, this argument fails, as then $A+B=\bigcup _{a\in A}a+B$ is still true but this is not a countable union. The Cantor set illustrates that the measure of $A+B$ can then indeed increase.